# Laravel Job for Bulk Mail

Tags: php, laravel, swiftmailer, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

this is the first time I am using laravel queue jobs, and somehow i could not get it working.

This is my mail class:

```
class TopluKabulMektubu extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $letter;

    public function __construct(AcceptLetter $letter)
    {
        $this->letter = $letter;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        $letter = $this->letter;

        return $this->subject('Mail Title')
            ->view('emails.topluKabulSon')
            ->attach(public_path($letter->pdf), [
                            'as' => 'AcceptanceLetter.pdf',
                            'mime' => 'application/pdf',
                        ]);
    }
}
```

And I created a function inside my AcceptanceLetter model to use mail easier :

```
public function sendAcceptanceLetter(){
        Mail::to('******@gmail.com')->queue(new TopluKabulMektubu($this));
        if(Mail::failures()){
                   $this->email_send = 2;
                   $this->save();
                }else{
            $this->email_send = 1;
            $this->save();

                }
    }
```

I created a queue table with php artisan queue:table and migrated, also changed queue connection to database from env file.

And my job file:

```
class QueueJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    protected $letter;
    
    public function __construct($letter)
    {
        //
        $this->letter = $letter;
    }

    
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->letter->sendAcceptanceLetter();
    }
}
```

Web route triggers my job :
`Route::get('/topluDeneme', [PaginationController::class, 'topluQueue']);`

And the controller:

```
public function topluQueue(){
        $letters = AcceptLetter::where('email', '!=', null)->where('passport_number','!=','0');

        foreach($letters as $letter){
            QueueJob::dispatch($letter);
        }
    }
```

I expect when i run php artisan queue:listen on terminal and go to /topluDeneme route, mails to be sent. But nothing happens on terminal, mails not sent and nothing changes on job datatable.

Answer (score 0):

I found whats wrong with my code. It seems I forgot to use get() in the controller, here is the correct version :

```
public function topluQueue(){
    $letters = AcceptLetter::where('email', '!=', null)->where('passport_number','!=','0')->get();

    foreach($letters as $letter){
        QueueJob::dispatch($letter);
    }
}
```